# how to access to my locals.user variable from a javascript file

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm using passport for my nodejs application, the session is working fine, I can access to my Object user from my views  thanks to my global variable 'res.locals.user = req.user', but when I attempt to access to it from a javascript file located in my public folder/javascripts/file.js, my object user is not defined there.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because is a server variable and you can only acces it within your teamplate. One solution is to create a variable in to global scope in your template and later use it in your js file.
For example if you are using jade, in your template you can do :

```
script.
  var myVar = !{myVar};
script(src='yourScript')
```

Comment: Thank you jose for you response,will it work if I create a controller.js  in my routes folder and  put my code there instead of using public folder  ,

Comment: I dont know what you want to say with controllers in your routes, but this will work for scripts required in your template after the script which declare your variable.